# toggle button in listview clicking on itself

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, sharedpreferences, togglebutton

Hi I am trying to create an app that lets you select interests from an listview, I created my own custom adapter with a textView and toggle button when clicked on a toggle button that particular value is added to shared preferences to remember for later use,
the problems i am facing are:

1) when i click the toggle button of a particular item of list another also gets clicked
2) when i scrawl up and down in the list automatically other items are clicked

userInterestList is the shared preference list which is initially empty and  interestList_Item is also a shared preference string array which is already initialized

```
    public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int i=getCount()-1;
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return interestList_Item.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return interestList_Item[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) InterestsActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.interest_list_item, parent,false);
        }
        final TextView userName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
        final ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton)convertView.findViewWithTag("toggle");
        Log.d("","userInterestList : "+userInterestList+"  interestList_Item:"+interestList_Item.toString());            
        if(userInterestList.contains(interestList_Item[position]))
             toggle.setChecked(true);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method 
                if(isChecked){
                    if(userInterestList.equals(""))
                        userInterestList = interestList_Item[position];
                    else
                        userInterestList = userInterestList+",new"+interestList_Item[position];
                    _appPrefs.saveUserInterestList(userInterestList);
                        Log.d("","check position :- "+position+" "+userInterestList+" "+interestList_Item[position]);
                } else {
                        userInterestList = userInterestList.replace(interestList_Item[position], "");
                        _appPrefs.saveUserInterestList(userInterestList);
                        if(userInterestList.contains(",new,new"))
                             userInterestList = userInterestList.replaceAll(",new,new",",new");
                        _appPrefs.saveUserInterestList(userInterestList);
                        Log.d("","uncheck position :- "+position+" "+userInterestList+" "+interestList_Item[position]);
                }
            }
        });
        userName.setText(interestList_Item[position]);
        Log.d("","num :"+i+"     username :"+userName.getText()+"        position:"+position);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Logs onstart:-

```
num :14     username :Cars        position:0
num :14     username :Business        position:1
num :14     username :Drinking        position:2
num :14     username :Travelling        position:3
num :14     username :Making recycled paper        position:4
num :14     username :Animal care        position:5
num :14     username :Organic farming        position:6
num :14     username :Cars        position:0
num :14     username :Business        position:1
num :14     username :Drinking        position:2
num :14     username :Travelling        position:3
num :14     username :Making recycled paper        position:4
num :14     username :Animal care        position:5
num :14     username :Organic farming        position:6
num :14     username :Ice skating        position:7
num :14     username :Cars        position:0
num :14     username :Business        position:1
num :14     username :Drinking        position:2
num :14     username :Travelling        position:3
num :14     username :Making recycled paper        position:4
num :14     username :Animal care        position:5
num :14     username :Organic farming        position:6
```

question:-
why first 7 list items showed so many times instead of all list items?

Logs on click toggle:-

```
    check position :- 0 Cars Cars
check position :- 6 Cars,newOrganic farming Organic farming
num :14     username :Cars        position:0
num :14     username :Business        position:1
num :14     username :Drinking        position:2
num :14     username :Travelling        position:3
num :14     username :Making recycled paper        position:4
num :14     username :Animal care        position:5
num :14     username :Organic farming        position:6
```

question:-
why are 2 items being selected when one is being clicked ?

Log when scrawling:-

```
num :14     username :Racing        position:8
num :14     username :Cars        position:0
num :14     username :Ice skating        position:7
num :14     username :Racing        position:8
num :14     username :Hunting        position:9
num :14     username :Gymnastics        position:10
num :14     username :Painting        position:11
num :14     username :Video gaming        position:12
num :14     username :Fishing        position:13
num :14     username :Swimming        position:14
num :14     username :Racing        position:8
num :14     username :Ice skating        position:7
check position :- 14 ,newOrganic farming,newSwimming Swimming
num :14     username :Organic farming        position:6
num :14     username :Animal care        position:5
num :14     username :Making recycled paper        position:4
num :14     username :Travelling        position:3
num :14     username :Drinking        position:2
num :14     username :Business        position:1
```

question:-
when scrawling why is it clicking on its own?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of reusing the `Views` in `Listview`..Here `setChecked()` method calls `onCheckedChangeListener`..so before `setChecked()` we make listener to `null`..after that we again set the listener..
change this line

```
 if(userInterestList.contains(interestList_Item[position]))
         toggle.setChecked(true);
```

into

```
  toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    if (userInterestList.contains(interestList_Item[position])) {
        toggle.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        toggle.setChecked(false);
    }
    //Here again set the listener as in your code..
```

keep remaining as usual and try..

Comment: wow straight shot... worked !!! but could you explain the views still did not get my mistake ... thanks a lot !!

Comment: @user3230689 getView() method retunrs the views which are alredy used..so that views already has a listener..setChecked method calls onChecked change listener if it is not null.thats why your method is calling..You are creating view with condition like if(Convertivew==null) that means converview not null reusing old view..

Comment: @kalyanpvs: Having similar problem. Can you please look into this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169131/android-adjacent-buttons-in-list-view-automatically-clicked   Thank you very much.