# Android- Adjacent buttons in list view automatically clicked

Tags: android, listview

I am working on a module that populates cart. I used `ListView` and extended `BaseAdapter` to populate the cart items.
With each of the item in `ListView`, I embedded two button(inc and dec) to increment and decrement quantity of item in cart.

`ListView` is correctly updated, but increment/decrement button on quick click/tapping shows abrupt behaviour.

Whenever I quickly tap any of inc or dec button, the corresponding inc or dec button of an item next to current item in `ListView` is automatically clicked(along with current item btn).

In other words, whenever I quickly tap inc btn of ith  item in `ListView`, inc btn of i+1 th item in `ListView` is automatically clicked( along with inc btn of ith item).

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_cart, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.baseItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qnt_tv);
        holder.qntInc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inc_btn);
        holder.qntDec = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dec_btn);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final CartModel cm = mCart.get(position);
    holder.baseItem.setText(cm.getmTitle());
    holder.qntSel.setText(String.valueOf(cm.getmQnt()));
    holder.qntInc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (qntSpinnerCb != null)
                qntSpinnerCb.changeQuantityOfSelectedItemInCart(cm.getmIid(), INCREASE_QNT);
        }
    });
    holder.qntDec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (qntSpinnerCb != null) {
                qntSpinnerCb.changeQuantityOfSelectedItemInCart(cm.getmIid(), DECREASE_QNT);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Interface for callback

```
public interface CartQntSpinnerListenerCallBack {
    void changeQuantityOfSelectedItemInCart(String iId, char changeType);
}
```

Tried debugging, unable to figure out this weird behavior.

Comment: You stress the term "quick tapping". So when you tap the buttons slowly or just once the adjacent item is not clicked?

Comment: Is the "baseItem" have fixed width? Positions of Inc/Dec buttons may change after changeQuantityOfSelectedItemInCart() and it causes abrupt behaviour.. I guess. (Or tapped while changing layouts)

Comment: Add the code for `qntSpinnerCb` and whatever it is touching.  The `OnClickListener()` instances seem reasonable.

Comment: Can you please show your xml code ?

Comment: What is mCart? I request you to post your complete adapter class if possible.

Comment: It's good to implement the interdace but you can directly assign the quantity using cm.setmQnt("your_incremnt_or_dec_qty") in your on click ...and call the notifydatasetchanged() ...

Answer (score 9):

You are not selecting correct `CartModel` inside `onClick`, if you want to get correct object inside `onclick` then you have to tag position to button

```
holder.qntInc.setTag(position);
```

**in onClick:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (qntSpinnerCb != null) {
        CartModel cm= mCart.get((Integer)view.getTag);
        qntSpinnerCb.changeQuantityOfSelectedItemInCart(cm.getmIid(), INCREASE_QNT);
    }
}
```

Follow the same for `qntDec`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep your current implementation, do this.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_cart, parent, false);
}

ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

holder.baseItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qnt_tv);
holder.qntInc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inc_btn);
holder.qntDec = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dec_btn);


...
```

Without seeing the rest of your code, however, I think you may want to reconsider how you are implementing BaseAdapter. Traditionally, they are used in conjunction with a list view to recycle views for efficiency. This means when a list scrolls a view out of frame, instead of redrawing the view - if(convertView == null) - it reuses it. What I think you are experiencing is that you are putting a click listener for two different objects on the same button.

What I would recommend doing is something more like this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public CartModel getItem(int position) {
    // mCart sounds like a single item but is a list? I advise you to rename
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // Implement with id. Copied the id call from your code..
    return getItem(position).getmIid();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_cart, parent, false);
    }

    CartModel cm = getItem(position);

    TextView baseItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qnt_tv);
    baseItem.setText(cm.getmTitle());

    // Organize like items together for readability
    TextView qntInc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inc_btn);
    qntInc.setTag(mCartKey, cm);
    qntInc.setOnClickListener(this);

    // readability
    TextView qntDec = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dec_btn);
    qntDec.setTag(mCartKey, cm);
    qntDec.setOnClickListener(this);


    // Defined in convert view?
    qntSel.setText(String.valueOf(cm.getmQnt()));


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.R.id.inc_btn:
            CartModel cm = (CartModel)v.getTag(mCartKey);
            // What is this?
            if (qntSpinnerCb != null)
                qntSpinnerCb.changeQuantityOfSelectedItemInCart(cm.getmIid(), INCREASE_QNT);

            break;


        case R.id.dec_btn:

            CartModel cm = (CartModel)v.getTag(mCartKey);
            if (qntSpinnerCb != null) {
                qntSpinnerCb.changeQuantityOfSelectedItemInCart(cm.getmIid(), DECREASE_QNT);
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

NOTE: BaseAdapter class must implement OnClickListener

Answer (score 1):

store the position of your view in your `viewholder` and use it every where in the `setonclicklistner` from `viewHolder` that position you will not see any absurd behaviour it will work as you want

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView baseItem, qntInc, qntDec;
    ....../* your code goes here */
    int position
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_cart, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.baseItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qnt_tv);
        holder.qntInc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inc_btn);
        holder.qntDec = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dec_btn);
        holder.position=position
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.position=position;
    }
    CartModel cm = mCart.get(holder.position);
    holder.baseItem.setText(cm.getmTitle());
    holder.qntSel.setText(String.valueOf(cm.getmQnt()));
    holder.qntInc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { 

            CartModel cm = mCart.get(holder.position);
            qntSpinnerCb.changeQuantityOfSelectedItemInCart(cm.getmIid(), INCREASE_QNT);
        }  
    });

    holder.qntDec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            CartModel cm = mCart.get(holder.position); 
            qntSpinnerCb.changeQuantityOfSelectedItemInCart(cm.getmIid(), DECREASE_QNT);

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

also check the value of `INCREMENT_QNT` and `DECREACE_QNT`

Comment: y have u voted down this solution this is tested n working code and also used in android developer site on this link(http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) so  update yourself dude before voting down the solution

Answer (score -1):

There is an issue in the code.

```
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_cart, parent, false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.baseItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qnt_tv);
    holder.qntInc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inc_btn);
    holder.qntDec = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dec_btn);

    // This should be added in the code
    holder.qntSel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sec_txt);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for the reason for down voting? The response is based on the input provided. If things should be assumed/understood without justification than everyone should be (over) professionals here and need no help. Sad..

Answer (score -1):

Your getter method `getmIid()` in `CartModel` has problem i suspect. This method is returning wrong index and so your next/previous button is updating

I suggest to use `position` integer in your callback `changeQuantityOfSelectedItemInCart()` first parameter. Because the position will always come correctly with `getView()` callback

**SOLUTION :**

```
    holder.qntInc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (qntSpinnerCb != null)
            qntSpinnerCb.changeQuantityOfSelectedItemInCart(position+"", INCREASE_QNT);
        }
    });
    holder.qntDec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (qntSpinnerCb != null)
            qntSpinnerCb.changeQuantityOfSelectedItemInCart(position+"", DECREASE_QNT);
        }
    });
```

The `position` is `int` type and your callback needs `String` so we should use    `position+""`

Hope this will work for you

Comment: What is reason for downvoting the answer? Atleast comment should be added for further modification in answer.. Unnecesorily downvoted every answer on this question..